# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (WEB PAGE NOT AVAILABLE) IONIC V4 APP

Tags: sapui5, ionic4, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, sap-smp

i am added kapsel plugins to my ionic app.and generated build and installed apk in app.i am getting this error

```
web page at http://localhost/smp/ui/iab.html could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

```
ionic cordova plugin 
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
kapsel-plugin-authproxy 4.2.8 "AuthProxy"
kapsel-plugin-corelibs 4.2.8 "CoreLibs"
kapsel-plugin-i18n 4.2.8 "i18n"
kapsel-plugin-inappbrowser 4.2.8 "InAppBrowser"
kapsel-plugin-logon 4.2.8 "Logon"
kapsel-plugin-ui5 4.2.8 "ui5"
```

Please find attachment

```
https://odsol-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/gsreddy_ondevice_co_uk/EVT4LR3rt55Jk3IyCiLNHO8Bkd8rxYZnFAdzAw2wbcaolA?e=HQgvC8
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would expect to see a port number next to the `localhost` url like the default `8100`:

```
http://localhost:8100/
```

Have you hardcoded the wrong url somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the replay @rtpHarry,But App is not running on any port. iam using this `alert( window.location.href)`.its displaying `http://localhost/home`